# d3js liner charts, how can I collapse empty areas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have d3 liner charts  and sometimes I am having empty intervals in the graph like this [image]

how can I collapse that empty spaces? and put some kind of message to show that the space here is collapsed?

Comment: There's nothing in D3 that would do this automatically. You'd have to break up your scale into several that are separated by the empty areas and then add something that shows that space has been collapsed yourself.

Comment: you mean to separate the chart into peaces?

Comment: That's essentially it, yes.

Comment: Also can I draw a rectangle in place of empty space? or this is also something that I cant do with d3 automatically?

Comment: D3 won't do this for you. You'll have to break up the chart.